# Get value from another function with JSON

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn Java and right now I have a little problem. I'm trying to get a value from a method to another:

```
public void Save(View v){
        Contador c = new Contador();
        c.nContador = "123";
        c.descricao = "Teste";
        c.tipoTarifa = "Tri";

        c.leituras = new ArrayList<Leitura>();

        Leitura l1 = new Leitura();
        l1.tipoLeitura = "HP";
        l1.valorLeitura = "321";

        Leitura l2 = new Leitura();
        l1.tipoLeitura = "HV";
        l1.valorLeitura = "654";

        c.leituras.add(l1);
        c.leituras.add(l2);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(c);
        System.out.print(json);
    }

public void Read(View v){
    Toast
            .makeText(this, "I want the json here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    }
```

So I have 2 buttons: one for save and one for read. When I press "Save" the method "Save" is called and it creates the string json. 
I want to get that same string when i click the button "Read".
How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need to return the string `json` from your `Save` method?

Comment: So I have 2 buttons, one for save and one for read. When i click "Save", i create the String json. I want to get that same string when i click the button "Read".

Comment: [whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Please use the [Java Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for naming classes, attributes and methods. The method name should be in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

---

**Approach 1**

You can return the generated string in `save()` and call it in `read()` to get it.

```
public String save(View v) {
    // beginning of implementation ommitted for brevity
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(c);
    return json;
}

public void read(View v) {
    String json = save(v);
    Toast.makeText(this, json, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I **do not** recommend doing it as you would create a dependency to `save()` in your `read()` method.

---

**Approach 2**

Same approach as before but without the dependency, using an auxiliary method.

```
public String save(View v) {
    // beginning of implementation ommitted for brevity
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(c);
    return json;
}

public void read(View v, String json) {
    Toast.makeText(this, json, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void process(View v) {
    String json = save(v);
    read(v, json);
}
```

I still **do not** recommend doing it as you would not sotre the string anywhere else, and everytime you called `process()` to get the input needed to `read()` you would make an indirect call to `save()`.

---

**Approach 3**

Set a class attribute containing the created string and use it in `read()`.

```
public class StackOverflowExample {

    private String json;

    public String save(View v) {
        // beginning of implementation ommitted for brevity
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        json = gson.toJson(c); // save the JSON in your class attribute
        System.out.print(json);
    }

    public void read(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, json, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Both approaches works wonders. It was so simple, sorry for such a dumb question. Thank you!

Comment: I added a new approach, but still recommend the third one. It's a better design to tackle this problem.